# How to fix on Mobile Devices? Custom CSS. (Wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress

On mobile devices, my post's title and date are clashing and overwriting each other. This looks awful. Here is my site. http://defensionem.com/200-russian-soldiers-along-with-t-90-tanks-in-syria/

It is on Wordpress.[image]

How do I fix this? There are no options in the Theme and I can use Custom CSS.

I tried to hide the date but it did not work.

```
.meta--items_fl{
display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do here is write media queries to hide specific elements or change their related css at certain screen lengths. For example,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    div.meta--items.fl {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

The above code would hide the date at a screen width of 700px and below. You can mess around with the width the breakpoint triggers to see what works best for you.

To learn more about media queries, you check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) out. Hope that helps!